# SQL query joing two tables on a date where one is a Numeric date (number of days) from unixepoch

Tags: sql, date, sqlite

I am trying to join two tables on a date column, the only issue is one date is formatted as an integer, it is the number of days from 1970-01-10 (unixepoch). The other date is formatted as a date in the MM/DD/YYYY format. What function will allow me to essentially convert the numeric date by adding the days to the unixepoch? I have tried the query below but it overwrites all the dates as 1970-01-01 or produces an error.

```
INNER JOIN table3 AS T3
   ON T3.date = DATE(T1.date, 'unixepoch')
```

some random examples from the database

1. T1.Date       T3.Date
2. 17432         12/28/2017
3. 17460         12/20/2017
4. 17464         12/25/2017
5. 17440         12/17/2017
6. 17500         12/05/2017

Update: I have converted the T1.Date to a DATE using the following Select statement, still looking to figure out how to convert the 'text' MM/DD/YYYY T3.Date in order to join

```
SELECT DATE('1970-01-01',  '+' || T1.Date || ' day') FROM T1
```

Comment: Use `datetime(T1.date, 'unixepoch')`, but the bigger problem are your dates which you have unwisely stored as `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: this is a .sqlite database that i am pulling into python using sqlite3, I have tried a select statement with DATETIME(T1.date, 'unixepoch') but it seems to add the Numeric Date as minutes rather than days? my output looks like the following 1970-01-01 04:51:32 for one example row, it will not produce matches as well

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen would you have any suggestions on converting the MM/DD/YYYY format to YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: @mitch The best course of action is to _not_ store your dates in anything other than an ISO compliant format.  This means year, month, day.  My answer might get you around the problem for now.

Comment: Use `substr(T3.Date,7) || substr(T3.Date,1,2) || substr(T3.Date,4,2)` to form an ISO date from T3.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following join logic:

```
FROM table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN table3 AS T3
    ON substr(T3.Date,7) || substr(T3.Date,1,2) || substr(T3.Date,4,2)  =
       datetime(T1.date, 'unixepoch')
```

Note that while it is bad to store your dates in the format `MM/DD/YYYY` as text, it might be equally bad to store dates as different formats.

Answer (score 0):

The date/time functions are highly database-specific.  However, I would do this by converting the unix epoch format to a date:

```
from table1 t1 join
     table3 t3
     on t1.date = date '1970-01-01' + t3.date * interval '1 day'
```

I should note that Unix epoch usually refers to the number of seconds or milliseconds since 1970-01-01, but that is easily adjusted in the `interval` expression.

The above is ANSI SQL.  Hence, it probably only works as written in Postgres.  But similar functionality is available in other databases, just with different syntax.

Comment: Hi Gordon, there is no formal date type in SQLite.  Rather, dates are just stored as plain text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Is this tagged SQLite?

Comment: Check the comments, he does eventually reveal that it is SQLite.  Or, you could search for `SQL unixepoch` ... that would bring up a bunch of SQLite hits.